# How can I visualize specific columns using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I built the following VBA code that automatically creates the PIVOT table and the charts on a new worksheet. 
The Pivot table is fine. The Bar chart is fine too. However, the Pie Chart (chart 2) is picking the "closed" column data (Column 1 in the Pivot table) from the Pivot table. I want it to pick the Grand total column, which is column 3 in the PT.

I tried to change the range on the top of the code, but it didn't work. I also removed the bar chart and executed with the PT and the Pie chart only and still same problem (the data is reading from the "Closed" column only).

Attachment: Contains screenshot of the output.

[image: A screenshot of the output]

Here is my code below:

```
  Sub PT_C_RiskType_Status()


    'Defining the variables

    Dim pc As PivotCache
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim sh As Shape
    Dim sh1 As Shape
    Dim ch As Chart
    Dim ch1 As Chart

     Set pc = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
    SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
    SourceData:="DataSource", _
    Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15)

    Set ws = Sheets.Add

    ws.Select
    Cells(3, 1).Select
    Range("A3").Select

     'Create the pivot table
      Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=ws.Name & "!R3C1", TableName:="Pivottable")

     'Adding the data fields
       pt.AddDataField _
        Field:=pt.PivotFields("Status"), _
        Function:=XlConsolidationFunction.xlCount
        'Adding the fields
       pt.AddFields _
        RowFields:="Risk Type", _
        ColumnFields:="Status", _
        PageFields:=Array("Date Received", "Risk Level")

    'Adding formatting options
  pt.DataFields(1).NumberFormat = "0"

     'Adding Filters for the pivot

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotFields("Date Received")
        .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotFields("Date Received"). _
        EnableMultiplePageItems = True


        With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotFields("Risk Level")
        .PivotItems("N/A").Visible = False
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotFields("Risk Level"). _
        EnableMultiplePageItems = True

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotFields("Risk Type")
        .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotFields("Status")
        .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
    End With
     'Adding chart
    Set sh = ws.Shapes.AddChart2( _
                XlChartType:=XlChartType.xlColumnStacked, _
                Width:=350, Height:=300)

    Set sh1 = ws.Shapes.AddChart2( _
                XlChartType:=XlChartType.xlPie, _
                Width:=200, Height:=200)

    Set ch1 = sh1.Chart
    Set ch = sh.Chart
    'The position of the chart (the Column Stacked Chart)
    ch.SetSourceData pt.TableRange1
    sh.Top = pt.TableRange1.Top
    sh.Left = pt.TableRange1.Left + pt.TableRange1.Width + 10
    'The position of the chart1 (The Pie Chart)
    sh1.Left = sh.Left - sh.Width
    'Formatting for chart and chart1
    'Colors the area for "Opened" status

    ch.FullSeriesCollection(2).Select
    With Selection.Format.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent4
        .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
        .ForeColor.Brightness = 0.400000006
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With
 'Colors the area for "Closed" status
    ch.FullSeriesCollection(1).Select
    With Selection.Format.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent3
        .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
        .ForeColor.Brightness = -0.25
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With
   'Formatting the labels inside the bars
    'Adding data labels to the bars
      ch.ApplyDataLabels (xlDataLabelsShowValue)
   'Formatting Chart1 (Pie Chart)


    ch1.ChartTitle.Select
    Selection.Delete    'Delete the title

    'Changing the color of the second portion of the chart
    ch1.FullSeriesCollection(1).Select
    ch1.FullSeriesCollection(1).Points(2).Select
    With Selection.Format.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent4
        .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
        .ForeColor.Brightness = 0.400000006
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With
   ' Moving the chart to the bottom of the pivot table
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 2").IncrementLeft 2.5
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 2").IncrementTop 97.5

End Sub
```

Please advise.

Thank you.

Comment: trimming your code to show a [mcve] will help us help you easier

Comment: When adding charts via code it's a good idea to first remove any "default" series which might have been added, then explicitly add the data you want to be displayed.  You set the data for `ch`, but not for `ch1`